# Remove padding on 1 item only

Tags: html, css, border, gallery, padding

I have a small issue with a website I'm creating.
The page has a background and a white body in the center, in the white body there is padding for the text so it doesn't start at the border.

```
#content
{ width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 31px;
  background: #FFFFFF; 
  text-align: left;}
```

So the problem is I have a jquery gallery in the top of the content body, but I don't want the gallery to have the padding around it, I mean, the white body. I want the gallery to start at the border of the body and end at the other end.
So I figured I have to make a new CSS tag without padding or negative padding but that isn't working.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative margins that match the padding amount to make the gallery flush with the edges.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
#content {
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 31px;
  background: #FFFFFF; 
  text-align: left;
}
.flush {
  background: #171717;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 -30px 0 -31px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>normal</div>
  <div class="flush">flush</div>
</div>
```